# How can I setup a dual-head display in portrait mode? (Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, xrandr, multi-monitor, monitors

I have two monitors on my desk in portrait orientation.

One is plugged in with a DVI cable and the other with a VGA (I don't have two DVI cables available) into my [Gigabyte Radeon 7750 HD](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CFgQFjAB&url=http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4345&ei=s8XeUeW2K6O-yQHk6YDoCw&usg=AFQjCNGaVvN3EdgJpndMmdYbuFwI4fWJQA&sig2=H9RdDnhBtbIH1udz0drt-g) graphics card. 
[image]

In Arch I installed `xf86-video-ati` from the official repository.
When I boot the machine both monitors are recognized and cloned in landscape position.

I generated xorg.conf with `Xorg --configure` and file is located at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.
Inside of my xorg.conf at the end of all of the "ScreenX" sections I have added `Option "RandRRotation" "True"`

Now if I run `xrandr --output DVI-1 --right-of VGA-0` the monitors will both be recognized as separate (not cloned displays anymore) and I am able to drag windows across the screens properly. However if I run `xrandr --output DVI-1 --rotate right` nothing happens, the same for VGA-0. I have also tried `xrandr -o 1` this turns off all of the screens until I run `xrandr -o 0` which only turns one display (VGA-0) back on.

How can I get the screens to rotate to portrait?

Comment: How's your neck so far?

Comment: Heh, that's why I would like to see if I can fix the rotation :)

Comment: For sure, I imagine it'd be pretty dang painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to rotate my screens by installing the proprietary [AMD Catalyst drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) for my graphics card and editing `xorg.conf`.

After installing the drivers I added the line `Virtual 4096 4096` to my `xorg.conf` under all of the `ScreenX` sections. I was then able to use `xrandr` properly.